# show previous/next post orderer by title in custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, order, next-post-link, previous-post-link

What's a working method to show link to next and previous same custom post type article, ordered by title and not id? (generally applying a filter to the order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a filter like the following to adjust the order of a post type archive, then the next & previous links will work perfectly without need for modification:

```
function wpse_139866_set_order_by( $wp_query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $wp_query->is_post_type_archive( 'my_post_type' ) && $wp_query->is_main_query() ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_139866_set_order_by' );
```